# git push на удаленный сервер не выполняет изменения

Tags: git, git-push

Есть сервер А, на нем развернут локальный гит.
Если я пытаюсь отправить изменения с своего компьютера на этот сервер, то информация о изменении доходит: в git log есть запись о комите, но изменения не применяются.

т.е. Если я изменил файл А, который был в гите, добавив в него строку, сделал комит и отправил на удаленный сервер. на удаленном сервере в git log есть мой комит, в git status отображается этот файл с пометкой modified, содержимое файла такое же, как до комита.

При пуше, комите и т.д. ошибок не выдает, говорит, что все отлично

Comment: Да, забыл вопрос, в чем может быть проблема, как сделать, что бы изменения автоматически применялись при комите?

Comment: В Вашей схеме никак. Ибо это костыль. working dir не будет менятся. Нужно на сервере делать pull/checkout

Comment: Может можно хук какой то написать? Просто идея такая, что основной сайт находится во внешней среде, у хостинг провайдера, а git на сервере в локальной сети, без доступа во внешнюю среду.

Comment: конечно можно. Только на сервере нужен так называемый bare репозитарий (можно конечно и без него, но не нужно). и правильный хук, который скачает и развернет.

Answer (score 0):

В файл конфигурации необходимо добавить следющие строчки:
    [receive]
        denyCurrentBranch = updateInstead
Работает с версии 2.3, позволяет пушить в "локальную" репу, без всяких костылей.